# How to limit the amount of input text of a UITextField based on the visible size of the TextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikit

I have a form app that contains a number of different sized UITextFields. I want to limit the amount of input text to how much text a textfield can hold before truncating the string. All of the other answers on stack overflow seem to know limit the amount of characters before hand (Ex. I want to limit to 40 characters), but I need to know how to limit it based on size of the textfield (which varies from textfield to textfield).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I just updated my answer using the textField.layoutMargins.left and textField.layoutMargins.right properties for greater accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the length of a string depends on the characters, you can't determine the max number of characters before knowing them, so I recommend testing whether or not each character input fits into the text field as you go along, ex:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // Combine the new text with the old
    NSString *combinedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]];

    // See if the width of the combined text + the text field's
    // left layout margin + the text field's right layout margin
    // is greater than or equal to the width of the textField
    // (I've multiplied the right margin by 2 to prevent the cursor
    // from shifting the field one extra character when the text field
    // if full)
    CGFloat textWidth =  [combinedText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: textField.font}].width + textField.layoutMargins.left + textField.layoutMargins.right * 2;
    CGFloat textFieldWidth = textField.frame.size.width;

    // If the text + margins is as wide or wider than the text field
    // don't add the new character, i.e. return NO. Else add the
    // character by returning YES.
    if (textWidth >= textFieldWidth) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: @GoshDangitBobby Glad to hear :) P.S. And great name! I felt super cool typing it in before writing that sentence. gosh dang it ;)